# Configure Nginx to support clients that require DH parameters of 1024 or smaller without weaking security for everyone else?

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

A third party's web tool that accesses our web server appears to be using Java 6, which does not support DH parameters > 1024 bits. It can't connect to our server because we have a dhparams file set to 4096 bits.

In Nginx, the dhparams file is set in `nginx.conf`, using the `ssl_dhparam` parameter.

Presumably, if we regenerate the dhparams.pem file with 1024 bits, this will weaken security for everyone.

Is there any way to let this one legacy client connect with 1024 bit dhparams, while using 4096 for everyone else? To make matters more complicated, it appears that Java 6 doesn't have SNI support.

Is there a good way to handle this situation?

Comment: This is the 10,000th Nginx question asked here.

Comment: Even _computing your own_ 1024-bit DH parameters rather than using the default will improve your position somewhat. The _correct_ thing to do, of course, is to update or decommission the third party garbage, and that of course should be your first, second, third and fourth option. In case you need it, the discussion of why 1024-bit DH parameters are weak is at https://weakdh.org/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client does not announce in the handshake which DH key strength it supports so the server cannot use a different DH key for different clients. But, the DH key is only used if DH ciphers are used. Modern clients prefer ECDHE instead and if your nginx accepts this preference then the handshake will not use the DH param at all since it will not do a DHE key exchange but an ECDHE key exchange. For configuration examples which prefer ECDHE see https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/.

As for clients without SNI: they will simply use the default host configured in nginx. Thus if you have a proper certificate there which matches all the names the non-SNI aware client might use to connect to your server then it should work.

Comment: Java 6 is ancient and many years out of support. I don't think it supported ECDHE.

Comment: Accepting, because I guess the answer is "it cannot be done". The more I investigate this, the more I suspect that I may just be getting the runaround from this other company. The most I could pry out of their (lack of) support was "it's your SSL configuration" and they linked to SSL labs, "which will help your technical team to fix the issue". We have an "A" on SSL Labs and the only clients in SSL labs that had issues were IE6/XP and Java 6. This is good info though, since now I understand DH better.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Java does not support ECDHE, but I did not claim that it does. It definitely does not count as a modern client.

Comment: Java 6 is as ancient as Android 2.3 or OpenSSL 0.9.8. To support these obsolete clients you should deploy TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA cipher suite for them, and TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_* for anything else.